# how to maintain queue number in sql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a `waitlist` table with a many to many relation to an `attendee` table.

Basically, a list of attendees in a waitlist...I need to store where each attendee is on the waitlist. I.E. `order_number`  is a auto-incremental unique int: 1,2,3,4,5,6...

**Waitlist_Attendee Table**
 id
 attendee_id_fk
 waitlist_id_fk
 order_number

My problem is if I have a bunch of attendees in a waitlist, how do I update the order_number if I later remove an attendee from the waitlist? Say `order_number=1` gets deleted from the waitlist. I need to update `order_number=2` so it is now `order_numer=1` and continue on for each `order_number` and so forth...

Is there an SQL method to auto-reoder the numbers so it is always a sequential list? or do I need to write a sort function to number them?

Or is there a better way I am not aware of?

Comment: Something like "`update waitlist_attendee set order_number = order_number - 1`"?

Comment: `UPDATE Waitlist_Attendee SET order_number = order_number-1`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear with my question. I updated it. What I am asking isn't how to update 1 field but to update all the fields and reorder the numbers after a deletion.

Comment: Have you tried the statement? Your question still reads as if it could fit.

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood the statement... yes that would work for deleted order_number=1 since you need to subtract 1 from all fields. It would not work for any other records being removed though from the waitlist though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just need to loop thru your attendees and change the order number.

```
$waitList = WaitList::with(['attendees' => function($q){
$q->orderBy('order_number');
})->find(1);

$count = 1;
foreach($waitList->attendees as $attendees)
{
 WaitList::find(1)->attendees()->updateExistingPivot($attendees->id, ['order_number' => $count]);
$count++;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right and this is the only way. Also, thanks for showing the code. I am not very good with eloquent still. I am confused by your use of `->find(1)` though. Why not use `->get()` in the query? And in the loop why `Waitlist::find(1)` can we use `$attendees->updateExistingPivot(...`?

Comment: find is use if you'er searching based on it's primary key and it will return single object. get is use when you're filtering based on non-primary key. sample when you're using where('field1', '=', 'value')->where('field2', '=', value)->get(). and not that it returns a collection.

Comment: you can't use $attendees->updateExistingPivot(). you might want to check the code of BelongsToMany.php to check what is position.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered that you may not need to re-number? The number that is shown beside the list on output is a display-time event. As long as the list is created in ascending order, even if one is removed, then you can still select the top 10, even if the numbers go from 1 to 12, and #2 and #10 had been deleted for example. That is just a `LIMIT 10 ORDER BY id ASC` - and a loop that counts 1 to 10 for display (or even just show ten items with `OL` and `LI` tags to do the numbering in HTML).

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. Maybe I will leave it at that. I wanted to display the number to the users so they would know if they were next or 10 down the line. I was hoping there was a simple command to do this.